# How to pass common-lisp' local variable to maxima?

Tags: common-lisp, maxima

I am using [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/index.html) inside [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) and I want to do the following-simple demo for real time plotting without pause/delay-:

```
(loop for j from 1 below 10 do 
          #$plot2d(sin(x),[x,0,?j*%pi])$)
```

error:`range must be of the form [variable, min, max]; found: [x,0,%pi*j]`

I have to use setf/defvar, but I want to use local variables.

Questions:

- How to pass common-lisp' local variable to maxima?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that maxima looks up the symbol value, which would mean local variables can't be used. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by plotting "without pause/delay". Even if that worked, wouldn't the effect be exactly the same as just running `for j: 1 thru 9 do plot2d(sin(x), [x, 0, j*%pi]);` in maxima itself?

Comment: I mean by without pause/delay that a simple loop in lisp which would do some calculations from serial then plot them and it would wait-blocking- for the new data, so no need for pause. I want variables to go back and forth between them as I am more comfortable with lisp' data types. I am thinking of using tick and comma for that, but I am worried about customization and I think it's quite common usage case.

Answer (score 2):

Maxima uses only dynamic scope, not lexical scope. Maxima variables are implemented as Lisp symbols which are declared special. In order for J to be visible to Maxima, it must be declared special in one way or another (either via DEFVAR/DEFPARAMETER or (DECLARE (SPECIAL ...)), I forget if there are other ways).

I know this is not satisfying since dynamic scope makes it possible to have name collisions and therefore subtle bugs. Maybe you can ensure there are no name collisions by using a gensym; maybe write a macro to substitute a gensym for another variable and declare the gensym special, something like that.

Comment: I am using strings as maxima code see my answer. Could you provide some sample code for gensym method?

Comment: I just mean that you would want, in effect, something like `(loop for g1234 ... do (declare (special g1234)) (meval (subst 'g1234 'j myexpr)))` where `myexpr` is a Maxima expression (e.g. something like `((MPLUS) $X $Y)`) which was obtained via MREAD-RAW (see src/nparse.lisp) or other means; I assume that you could create a macro to automate this construction.

Answer (score 0):

I am suing this macro:

```
(defmacro with-maxima (&body body)
  "write normal maxima exprs."
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (slot)
                 (destructuring-bind (&body args) slot
                   `(maxima:displa ,(read-from-string (concatenate 'string
                                                            "#$" (princ-to-string args) "$")))))
               body)
     ,(read-from-string "#$reset()$")
     ,(read-from-string "#$kill(all)$")))
```

example :

```
(with-maxima
  "y3: k-y1-2*y2"
  "gradef(y1,t,v1)"
  "gradef(y2,t,v2)"
  "gradef(v1,t,a1)"
  "gradef(v2,t,a2)"
  "diff(y3,t)")
```

Comment: Looks good to me. I think there are other ways to achieve the same effect, but I don't see anything wrong with the stuff you've shown here. Is there something more that you are not getting with this implementation? What is the bigger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to use code completion: when I write ( it doesn't close automatically. And it would great to disable read dispatch macro #$,so I can make macro works without using read-string. And I want to disable regarding y3: as an error outside "". I want to write the same code for maxima ,but with an additional key for lisp variables.

Comment: About "disable read dispatch macro #$,so I can make macro works without using read-string": well, #$ calls MREAD or MREAD-RAW (I forget which) so you can omit #$ but then you need to parse the string yourself, or construct the expression yourself, e.g. `(cons '(mplus) '(1 2 3 4))`. About "disable regarding y3: as an error": I don't understand what you mean. About "write the same code for maxima ,but with an additional key for lisp variables": I don't understand what you mean. As I was saying, it would help to explain your goals here. What is the program you are writing supposed to do?

Comment: I want to use maxima inside a lisp used for robot control and dynamical systems, so control in lisp and dynamical system stuff in maxima. I like to work in one environment "lisp". So "write the same code for maxima ,but with an additional key for lisp variables" = code like (with-maxima (y3: 1+2+ :lisp i) 1+2 (plot2d(..))). :lisp could be anything which the macro would search for it.  "disable regarding y3: as an error" = the previous code has y3: and lisp interpret it as a wrong keyword.

Comment: OK, sounds like a good project. There are various ways to about merging Maxima and Lisp, and the way that you have ($# + special variables) seems workable and not obviously inferior to some other approach. The only way I know to avoid parsing a string by some means is to construct Lisp expressions which correspond to Maxima expressions (`(cons '(mplus) '(1 2 3 4))` mentioned above). Incidentally if you have questions which require some discussion, you should probably ask on the maxima-discuss mailing list. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss